# Unwanted text highlighting in Vim latex-suite

Tags: vim, colors, syntax-highlighting

I have installed vim latex-suite. Whenever I type`$$` to get inside math mode, as a side effect, it also highlights the last search term using `/exp`. What has caused this and how can I avoid this highlighting when I type `$$` without affecting the functioning of latex-suite?

Comment: The general opinion on #vim is that latexsuite is bloated and not a particularly good plugin.  If you asked there they'd likely just tell you to get rid of it altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer.

If you want to use `vim` to write your `latex` documents `latex-suite` isn't recommended anylonger, at least from my perspective. There are several more comprehensive vim-scripts which handle this task a lot better.

It is worth to take a look at

> http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/

and

> https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box

**LaTeX-Box**

In the case you want a lightweight environment and a fast learning progress you should try `LaTeX-Box`. The documentation is very legible and after a short period of time you know the important commands.

**Automatic LaTeX Plugin**

`atp` is everything in one at the expense of a rather steep learning curve and a bit bloated. The documentation is quite long and you need a bit of time for deeper insights.

Both scripts are at least a lot better maintained than `latex-suite` and have a mailing-list i.e. an issue tracker. So there is no need to stick with `latex-suite` anylonger.